# Brand New Macbook Pro Having Trouble Running Gatsby Theme Apollo Docs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't seem to get this project running on my new Macbook Pro:

https://github.com/apollographql/gatsby-theme-apollo/tree/main/packages/gatsby-theme-apollo-docs

This is the command to run:

npm install gatsby-theme-apollo-docs

I get all of these "could not resolve dependency" warnings, I have tried running:

npm audit fix

and

npm audit fix --force

But still cannot get this project to run.  This is what it says when I run it:

```
@MBP16inch2021 test % sudo npm install gatsby-theme-apollo-docs 
Password:
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: gatsby-theme-apollo-docs@5.3.1
npm WARN Found: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-docs/node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from recompose@0.30.0
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-docs/node_modules/recompose
npm WARN     recompose@"^0.30.0" from gatsby-theme-apollo-docs@5.3.1
npm WARN     node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-docs
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@">=16.9.0" from gatsby-theme-apollo-docs@5.3.1
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-docs
npm WARN   gatsby-theme-apollo-docs@"^5.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-use@9.12.0
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   18 more (@apollo/space-kit, @emotion/core, @emotion/styled, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-use@9.12.0
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-core/node_modules/react-use
npm WARN   react-use@"^9.11.0" from gatsby-theme-apollo-core@3.0.35
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-core
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-use@9.12.0
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-core/node_modules/react-use
npm WARN     react-use@"^9.11.0" from gatsby-theme-apollo-core@3.0.35
npm WARN     node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-core
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-use@9.12.0
npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@">=16.8" from @tippyjs/react@4.2.5
npm WARN   node_modules/@tippyjs/react
npm WARN     @tippyjs/react@"^4.0.0" from @apollo/space-kit@5.6.3
npm WARN     node_modules/@apollo/space-kit
npm WARN   11 more (apollo-algolia-autocomplete, framer-motion, gatsby, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.8.0" from react-use@9.12.0
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-core/node_modules/react-use
npm WARN   react-use@"^9.11.0" from gatsby-theme-apollo-core@3.0.35
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-core
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.8.0" from react-use@9.12.0
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-core/node_modules/react-use
npm WARN     react-use@"^9.11.0" from gatsby-theme-apollo-core@3.0.35
npm WARN     node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-core
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @reach/router@1.3.4
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   18 more (@apollo/space-kit, @emotion/core, @emotion/styled, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"15.x || 16.x || 16.4.0-alpha.0911da3" from @reach/router@1.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@reach/router
npm WARN   @reach/router@"^1.3.4" from gatsby@2.32.13
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN   2 more (gatsby-link, gatsby-react-router-scroll)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"15.x || 16.x || 16.4.0-alpha.0911da3" from @reach/router@1.3.4
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@reach/router
npm WARN     @reach/router@"^1.3.4" from gatsby@2.32.13
npm WARN     node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN     2 more (gatsby-link, gatsby-react-router-scroll)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @reach/router@1.3.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@">=16.8" from @tippyjs/react@4.2.5
npm WARN   node_modules/@tippyjs/react
npm WARN     @tippyjs/react@"^4.0.0" from @apollo/space-kit@5.6.3
npm WARN     node_modules/@apollo/space-kit
npm WARN   11 more (apollo-algolia-autocomplete, framer-motion, gatsby, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"15.x || 16.x || 16.4.0-alpha.0911da3" from @reach/router@1.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@reach/router
npm WARN   @reach/router@"^1.3.4" from gatsby@2.32.13
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN   2 more (gatsby-link, gatsby-react-router-scroll)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"15.x || 16.x || 16.4.0-alpha.0911da3" from @reach/router@1.3.4
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@reach/router
npm WARN     @reach/router@"^1.3.4" from gatsby@2.32.13
npm WARN     node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN     2 more (gatsby-link, gatsby-react-router-scroll)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-side-effect@1.2.0
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   18 more (@apollo/space-kit, @emotion/core, @emotion/styled, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-side-effect@1.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-helmet/node_modules/react-side-effect
npm WARN   react-side-effect@"^1.1.0" from react-helmet@5.2.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-helmet
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-side-effect@1.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-helmet/node_modules/react-side-effect
npm WARN     react-side-effect@"^1.1.0" from react-helmet@5.2.1
npm WARN     node_modules/react-helmet
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: create-react-context@0.3.0
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   18 more (@apollo/space-kit, @emotion/core, @emotion/styled, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from create-react-context@0.3.0
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@reach/router/node_modules/create-react-context
npm WARN   create-react-context@"0.3.0" from @reach/router@1.3.4
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@reach/router
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from create-react-context@0.3.0
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@reach/router/node_modules/create-react-context
npm WARN     create-react-context@"0.3.0" from @reach/router@1.3.4
npm WARN     node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/@reach/router

up to date, audited 2746 packages in 6s

298 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

70 vulnerabilities (4 low, 30 moderate, 36 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I've restarted, installed latest version of node, react, etc.  Just cannot seem to get this thing to run and I don't know what I'm doing with this npm audit fix stuff, but nothing has resolved it.  Thanks for your help!

**Edit per the comments on this post I have tried a couple new commands:**

When I run

```
npm i react@16.14.0
```

I get:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: gatsby-theme-apollo-docs@5.3.1
npm WARN Found: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0" from @mdx-js/react@1.6.22
npm WARN   node_modules/@mdx-js/react
npm WARN     peer @mdx-js/react@"^1.0.0" from gatsby-plugin-mdx@1.10.1
npm WARN     node_modules/gatsby-plugin-mdx
npm WARN     1 more (the root project)
npm WARN   21 more (gatsby, @reach/router, create-react-context, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"17.0.2" from apollo-algolia-autocomplete@1.2.1
npm WARN node_modules/apollo-algolia-autocomplete
npm WARN   apollo-algolia-autocomplete@"^1.2.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: gatsby-theme-apollo-docs@5.3.1
npm WARN Found: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0" from @mdx-js/react@1.6.22
npm WARN   node_modules/@mdx-js/react
npm WARN     peer @mdx-js/react@"^1.0.0" from gatsby-plugin-mdx@1.10.1
npm WARN     node_modules/gatsby-plugin-mdx
npm WARN     1 more (the root project)
npm WARN   21 more (gatsby, @reach/router, create-react-context, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0" from recompose@0.17.0
npm WARN node_modules/recompose
npm WARN   recompose@"^0.17.0" from the root project

up to date, audited 2952 packages in 3s

324 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

62 vulnerabilities (30 moderate, 32 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

And when I run

```
npm i react-dom@16.14.0
```

I get:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: gatsby-theme-apollo-docs@5.3.1
npm WARN Found: react-dom@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.4.2 || ^17.0.0" from gatsby@2.32.13
npm WARN   node_modules/gatsby
npm WARN     peer gatsby@"^2.0.0" from babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries@2.16.1
npm WARN     node_modules/babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries
npm WARN     17 more (gatsby-plugin-algolia, ...)
npm WARN   11 more (@reach/router, gatsby-link, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"17.0.2" from apollo-algolia-autocomplete@1.2.1
npm WARN node_modules/apollo-algolia-autocomplete
npm WARN   apollo-algolia-autocomplete@"^1.2.1" from the root project

up to date, audited 2952 packages in 21s

324 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

62 vulnerabilities (30 moderate, 32 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: Two things: (1) All we've seen are install warnings, can you confirm that there are errors when you actually start the project? (2) Can you put up your whole package.json for the project into which you're installing?

Comment: Noob alert!  I was just running the install commands but not actually running the project with gatsby develop.  I'm so sorry for wasting your time! Thank you @msmith for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I see that you've used `sudo` in your code block above, which could cause issues, and is probably not what you want.

It seems likely to me that the issue is with peer dependency resolution. Though `npm audit` will flag potential vulnerabilities, but your application shouldn't fail because you haven't run it. The peer dependencies required by [gatsby-theme-apollo-docs@v5.3.1](https://github.com/apollographql/gatsby-theme-apollo/blob/3af8187c92ce59c9adee63b760268824ccc3ca74/packages/gatsby-theme-apollo-docs/package.json) are `gatsby@^2.13.80`, `react@>=16.9.0`, and `react-dom@>=16.9.0`. But it seems as though you have other packages installed which have incompatible requirements on these libraries (specifically the `react`). For instance:

```
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@">=16.9.0" from gatsby-theme-apollo-docs@5.3.1
npm WARN node_modules/gatsby-theme-apollo-docs
npm WARN   gatsby-theme-apollo-docs@"^5.3.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-use@9.12.0
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   18 more (@apollo/space-kit, @emotion/core, @emotion/styled, ...)
```

A close reading indicates that one of the peer dependencies listed by `react-use` is `react@17.0.2` which is incompatible with the version specified by `gatsby-theme-apollo-docs`.

There are two ways of approaching this problem:

1. You can force installation and hope that all your libraries work even if they don't all get the versions they say they need. Use the `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` flags when you run `npm install`.
2. You can go through the dependencies throwing warnings during install and downgrade/upgrade them until the peer dependencies of all your dependencies are actually in a compatible range.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have cloned the repository and gone into "gatsby-theme-apollo-docs" directory.  Then I have "npm install --force" and "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" and both commands return with 50+ vulnerabilities.  I'm not sure what you mean by your answer in #2 of going through dependencies and upgrade/downgrade them.  Could you maybe describe exactly what I should do to downgrade/upgrade to resolve the "react-use" requiring "react@17.0.2" situation you outlined above?  Maybe by seeing that example I'll get some momentum and be able to resolve the rest of the issues.

Comment: The idea is that you might need to install some of your libraries at earlier versions to keep them all compatible. If some dependency says it needs an older version of `react`, you'll need to install it at an earlier version to be compatible. If it needs a new version, you'll need to install it at a later version. Thinking about this particular case more, I would recommend you try to downgrade react itself: `npm i react@16.14.0` and `npm i react-dom@16.14.0`.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help and apologies for yet another post. I have gotten further but don't quite yet understand the situation enough to troubleshoot further.  I've edited the post with the output of both of the commands you gave me in your last comment.  Thank you for persevering here, feeling like an absolute noob.